# Winapp driver not support web elements

Tags: java, winappdriver

[image]

I'm automating my Windows application.

I'm using Winapp driver and Java language for automation. I am capturing the web elements using UI Spy Tool.

My application is loading, still I can't automate the login page.
I'm getting the following error:

**My Code:**

```
public class Reporter 
{

    private static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver;

    public static void main(String args[])  
                           throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException 
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        String homePath = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
        capabilities.setCapability("app",  homePath + "\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\2.0\\HHCZT7OJ.D37\\61K3K288.OXH\\base..tion_6e5be371fe594b2d_0001.0000_aad96dff3b16369b\\");
        WindowsDriver Session = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);

        Assert.assertNotNull(Session);
        Session.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        DesiredCapabilities Appcapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        Appcapabilities.setCapability("app", "Root");
        WindowsDriver AppSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), Appcapabilities);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(AppSession, 30);

        AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("txtUserName").sendKeys("r_nave");
        AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("txtPassword").sendKeys("naveen");
        AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("btnLogin").click();
    }

}
```

Error::

> Jul 16, 2018 10:19:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS Jul 16, 2018 10:19:47 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 0 milliseconds For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time:
>   '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z' System info: host: 'ANTONYW10', ip:
>   '10.246.0.91', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '10.0.1' Driver info:
>   io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver Capabilities [{app=Root,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, platform=XP}] Session ID:
>   BB465F8F-3CE3-453C-99CB-BB517378A6B2
>   *** Element info: {Using=accessibility id, value=txtUserName}

Now it's working for me that I put thread.sleep 20000

Comment: Can you paste uiSpy screenshot showing where did you take the data for your locator? Also why is there an empty value in findElementByAccessibilityId in your example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you provide the whole app schema? Where is this edit control nested in?
2. Have you tried first doing:

   `driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("txtUserName").click();
   driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("txtUserName").sendKeys("");`

Comment: Yes I tried this code, but its not working. getting same error

Comment: So where is nested this ControlType.Edit? Is it in some DataGrid?
Basically you need first to set focus on parent control, and then you can type the keys

Comment: I am unable to solve my issue, can you please help me. I have been trying to solve this since 2 day